# Using a environment variable defined in .bashrc from a bash script

Tags: bash, environment-variables

If we set custom environment variables in .bashrc like the following:

```
TMP_STRING='tmp string'
```

It seems like this variable is not directly accessible from the bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $TMP_STRING
```

I tried the following, but it also doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/.bashrc

echo $TMP_STRING
```

Could you suggest what would be the correct way in this case?
Thank you!

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "doesn't work".  What do you expect?  What actually happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `VAR=value` defines a *shell variable*. Environment variables live in a separate area of process memory that is preserved when another process is started, but are otherwise indistinguishable from shell variables.

To promote a variable to an environment variable, you must `export` it.

Example:

```
VAR=value
export VAR
```

or

```
export VAR=value
```

If you put the above into `.bashrc`, the above value of `$VAR` should be available in the script, but only if it's run from the login shell.

I would not recommend sourcing `.bashrc` in the script.  Instead, create a separate file named something like `.script.init.sh` and source that:

```
# script init
TMP_STRING='tmp string'
```

Your script:

```
# script
. ~/.script.init.sh
```

If this value must be available to any process spawned by the script, prefix it with `export` :

```
# script init
export TMP_STRING='tmp string'
```